# Why does Flash Player need "ttf-mscorefonts" in order for flash player to work?

Tags: flash, dependencies

Could someone tell me why Flash Player needs `ttf-mscorefonts` to work?

Answer (score 5):

In Flash IDE, when creating a text field, there are two options in terms of specifying a font:

- if a "normal" font is selected (i.e. Ubuntu or Droid or Comic Sans), outlines of the symbols used will be included in the swf file as vector shapes, so the text will be displayed identically on any platform
- there are also some special fonts: _sans, _serif and _monospace - when those are chosen, the outlines are not included in the file and Flash Player uses system fonts instead. Which, on Windows, are Times New Roman, Arial and Courier New.

Because Flash movies are authored predominantly on Windows, they're tested with those fonts present. I don't know if there's a hard dependency built into Flash player, but even if not, some/many movies will be displayed incorrectly if those fonts are missing.

Comment: There isn't a hard dependency on the MS core fonts in the packages, so I guess they are just recommended for things to look right in some Flash apps, as you suggest.