# Missing general fonts after installing WINE

Tags: installation, wine, fonts

I have problem with my font after installing flash & wine, font as Arial, Verdana, Comic SanMS, Times New Roman, Tahoma, etc not found on my system. how to install it?

Comment: Please remember to accept/upvote the best answer(s) to your question when possible (tick/check mark on the left). This way, the question is marked as "answered" and future readers can refer to it knowing the solution works. Thank you...:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install ttf-mscorefonts-installer available from the Ubuntu Software 
Centre:

[image: Install via the software center]

or (using the terminal Ctrl-Alt-T)

> sudo apt-get install msttcorefonts

Please review [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74322/why-does-flash-player-need-ttf-mscorefonts-in-order-for-flash-player-to-work) to understand why Flash needs these common Microsoft true type fonts to work properly